# Power BI - current week vs previous week

Tags: powerbi, dax

I’m looking for a formula to tell one column for current week and then previous week based on a id number

Example would be

Id -1234 (current week 20 sale’s previous week 25 sales)

I have a calendar created.

I am also trying to potentially see the sales data by weeks based on the dates, so I am using weeknum. It would be needing to have the ids and then the weeknum.

What are the formulas to this?

I have tried YouTube, but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the current week sales and previous week sales based on the ID number using Power BI, you can use the following DAX formulas:

Current Week Sales:

```
CurrentWeekSales = CALCULATE(SUM(SalesData[Sales]), 
    FILTER(SalesData, SalesData[WeekNum] = WEEKNUM(TODAY()) && SalesData[ID] = SELECTEDVALUE(SalesData[ID]))
)
```

Previous Week Sales:

```
PreviousWeekSales = CALCULATE(SUM(SalesData[Sales]), 
    FILTER(SalesData, SalesData[WeekNum] = WEEKNUM(TODAY()) - 1 && SalesData[ID] = SELECTEDVALUE(SalesData[ID]))
)
```

Replace "SalesData" with the actual name of your table that contains the sales data. "Sales" is the column representing the sales amount, "WeekNum" is the column representing the week number, and "ID" is the column representing the ID number.

Ensure that you have a relationship established between your calendar table (containing the week numbers) and the table containing the sales data based on the week number.

These formulas will calculate the sum of sales for the current week and previous week, filtered by the selected ID number. You can then use these measures in your Power BI visuals to display the desired information.

Comment: This answer was likely generated by ChatGPT.

Comment: @PeterMortensen is correct. At least three of your answers (and even your comment!) appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.